# Should the word "then" be used instead of the word "than"

Tags: conjunctions

"If a size '2' is beautiful, than my size '22' must be glorious."

I believe the word "then" should've been used instead of "than". Correct?

Comment: Where did you get this from?  Yes, you're correct. [General reference](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=use+of+then+vs+than&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: From a picture of a woman holding up a sign saying this quote

Answer (score 3):

You are right of course.

**Then** is used to demonstrate a sequence:

> *Then* has numerous meanings:
>    1. At that point in time, e.g.: I wasn't ready then. 
>    2. Next, afterward, e.g.: Do your homework and then go to bed 
>    3. In addition, also, on top of that, e.g.: It cost $5,000, and then there's tax too 
>    4. In that case, therefore (often with "if"), e.g.: If you want to go, then you'll    have to finish your homework.

```
Meaning 4 would apply to "then" in the O.P.'s quote.
```

**Than** is used in a comparison:

> Unlike *then*, *than* is not used to indicate a sequence, but in comparative
>   statements.
>
> E.g.: Tom is smarter than Bill.

Sources: [elearningenglish](http://www.elearnenglishlanguage.com/difficulties/thanthen.html) and [grammartips](http://grammartips.homestead.com/than.html)

Comment: Well, one could quibble that "than" CAN be related to time. Like you could write, "Al arrived later than Mary." The point is that it's used to identify the "target" of a comparison.

Comment: @Jay: In that case, you could use "then" in a comparison related sentence as well: We first compared length, then we compared size.

Comment: Ironically, by talking about time vs. comparisons, the error would be easy to make.  After all, aren't we "comparing" a Size 2 with a Size 22?  No, instead we're drawing a conclusion, so _then_ is used.  (I've edited the answer to remove the "time" requirement for _then_.)